# Parse info from a text file

Tags: powershell

I am running this command to pull the last line of a log file:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\MigrationJobStatus-20171020-123839-515.log |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

The results do give me the last line, but now I need to filter the results:

> 10/20/2017 12:38:56 PM  Information     [Event]: [JobEnd], [JobId]: [70b82296-b6e2-4539-897d-c46384619059], [Time]: [10/20/2017 12:38:49.074], [FilesCreated]: [0], [BytesProcessed]: [0], [ObjectsProcessed]: [34], [TotalExpectedSPObjects]: [34], [TotalErrors]: [19], [TotalWarnings]: [3], [TotalRetryCount]: [0], [MigrationType]: [None], [MigrationDirection]: [Import], [CreatedOrUpdatedFileStatsBySize]: [{}], [ObjectsStatsByType]: [{"SPUser":{"Count":1,"TotalTime":0,"AccumulatedVersions":0,"ObjectsWithVersions":0},"SPFolder": "Count":4,"TotalTime":629,"AccumulatedVersions":0,"ObjectsWithVersions":0},"SPDocumentLibrary":"Count":1,"TotalTime":68,"AccumulatedVersions":0,"ObjectsWithVersions":0},"SPFile":{"Count":13,"TotalTime":0,"AccumulatedVersions":0,"ObjectsWithVersions":0},"SPListItem":{"Count":16,"TotalTime":2240,"AccumulatedVersions":0,"ObjectsWithVersions":0}}], [CorrelationId]: [7bbf249e-701a-4000-8eee-c4a7ef172063]

I need to be able to pull the following and export to CSV:

```
[JobId]: [70b82296-b6e2-4539-897d-c46384619059]
[FilesCreated]: [0]
[BytesProcessed]: [0]
[ObjectsProcessed]: [34]
[TotalExpectedSPObjects]: [34]
[TotalErrors]: [19]
[TotalWarnings]: [3]
```

Can someone give me some ideas on how to accomplish this?
I am doing a OneDrive 4 Business migration and need to pull the results of the `Get-SPOMigrationJobProgress` log for a few thousand users.

Comment: I don't have a way to test, but you can try `Get-SPOMigrationJobProgress -nologfile | export-csv .\mylogfile.csv -notypeinformation` or something to that effect.

Comment: No, that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add other fields there and then save results using Out-File

```
$results = ""
$fields = @("[JobId]", "[FilesCreated]") 
$items = get-content c:\temp\MigrationJobStatus-20171020-123839-515.log | select-object -last 1 | %{ $_.Split(",")}
foreach($item in $items)
{
    $field = ($item.Split(":")[0]).Trim()
    if($fields.Contains($field)) { $results+= "$item`r`n" }
}

Write-Host $results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and grab the fields you need.

```
$text = get-content c:\temp\MigrationJobStatus-20171020-123839-515.log | select-object -last 1

$text = ($text -split ",").Trim(" ")
$csvtext = @"
$($text[3])
$($text[4])
$($text[5])
$($text[6])
$($text[7])
$($text[8])
"@

$csvtext | Out-File ".\logfile.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the fields that you want by using regular expression and then create a psobject from each match:

```
$regexPattern = '\[([^]]+)\]: \[([^]]+)\]'
$result = Get-Content c:\temp\MigrationJobStatus-20171020-123839-515.log | 
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Select-String -Pattern $regexPattern -AllMatches | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -match $regexPattern | 
                     Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$Matches[1]}},@{n='Value';e={$Matches[2]}} }
```

You can filter down the resulting object collection with `Where-Object` and use `Export-Csv` to get your result into a csv file.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. if I create a psobect, what do I use as the variable?  $object = [pscustomobject] {           JobID = $????

    FilesCreated = $???}. Thanks

Comment: @Chabango With the example above, you would find a collection of objects in the variable `$result`.